# Recortar imagen usando image tool component en cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

estoy usando un plugin

[Image tool component](https://github.com/raitisg/CakePHP-ImageTool-Component)

para lo cual he creado una función, que lo uso luego de cada subida de las imágenes de la siguiente manera

```
//Función para recotar imagen 
private function _risizeimage($image){
    $img = ImageTool::resize([
                    'input' => $image,
                    'output' => $image,
                    'width' => 100,
                    'height' => 100,
                    'keepRatio' => true,
                ]);
                return $img;
}
```

aqui la función para cargar las imagenes

```
public function publicadd() {

    $publicadd = $this->Advertisements->newEntity($this->request->data);
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $publicadd->id_user = $this->Auth->user('id_user');
        $publicadd = $this->Advertisements->patchEntity($publicadd,$this->request->data);
        if ($this->Advertisements->save($publicadd)) {
            $id = $publicadd->id_advertisement;
            $publicaddimg = $this->AdvertisementsImagenes->query();
            //Variable que uso para recuperar las imagenes cargadas
            $images = $this->request->data['name_imagen'];
            foreach ($images as $image){
                $imgname = $image['name'];
                // Variable para recortar imagen
                $img = $this->_risizeimage($imgname);
                $data = [
                    'id_advertisement' => $id,
                    'name_imagen' => $image['tmp_name']
                ];
                $publicaddimg->insert(['id_advertisement','name_imagen'])
                        ->values($data);
                new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'anuncios',true,0755);
                // Funcion para cargar imagen al servidor
                $mv = new File($img['tmp_name']);
                $mv->copy(WWW_ROOT . 'anuncios/'.$img['tmp_name']);
            }
            $publicaddimg->execute();
            $this->Flash->success('Anuncio Publicado');
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Home','action' => 'index']);
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error('Error al momento de guardar el registro');
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que no hace la subida y el recorte como tal no se si estoy haciendo algo mal, por favor ayuda llevo varios días con esto Gracias

Comment: Que version de php tienes en tu equipo? ya que indica que el tool component funciona con 5.4, en caso de versiones anteriores hay que reemplazar [] por array()

Comment: tengo el 5.6 de php

Comment: No sube el archivo, o no lo recorta, intenta colocar un bloque `try{...} catch(Exception $error){echo $error->getMessage();}` a tu función `publicadd`

Comment: Ya lo revise el problema estuvo en mi configuración dentro del server xampp (no estaba cargando el archivo dentro su propiedad tmp_name), ahora me surgio otro como hago para recuperar lo que la funcion me devuelve para subirlo luego

Comment: es la ruta `'output' => $image` que le indicas, si logra guardar la imagen, te retornara un `true`, y la imagen debe estar en el nombre que le indicas, lo que no estoy seguro es si reescribe, ya que estas indicando el mismo nombre

Comment: cuando hago `$imgname = $image['tmp_name']; $img = $this->_risizeimage($imgname); var_dump($img)` y me devuelve **resource(242) of type (gd)** no se que tengo que jalar del arreglo de la función

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51635/discussion-between-hammerffall-bk-and-jonathan-cunza).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final quedo de la siguiente forma, el metodo para recortar

```
private function _risizeimage($image,$output){ 
$img = ImageTool::resize(array( 
'input' => $image, 
'output' => $output, 
'width' => 100, 
'height' => 100, 
'keepRatio' => true, 
));     
return $img; 
}
```

la ejecución del foreach

```
foreach ($images as $image){ 
$imgname = $image['tmp_name']; 
$img = $this->_risizeimage($imgname, WWW_ROOT.'anuncions/'.$image['name']); 

}
```

Comment: eso lo colo dentro de la función _risizeimage?

Comment: si, la idea de tu función es retornar true o false haz esto `return ImageTool::saveImage(....);`, como te comento, la función te retorna un true si guarda la imagen en el nombre que le indiques o false en caso contrario, si no indicas nombre, te devuelve el mismo **resource gd** que indicaste

Comment: lo probe me sale error el siguiente `Notice (8): Undefined index: compression [ROOT\vendor\ImageTool.php, line 677] Notice (8): Undefined index: quality [ROOT\vendor\ImageTool.php, line 677] Notice (8): Undefined index: chmod [ROOT\vendor\ImageTool.php, line 677]`, al hacer `$img = $this->_risizeimage($imgname); var_dump($img);` me muestra lo mismo **resource(236) of type (gd)**

Answer (score 0):

Mi código lo tengo así ahora

```
private function _risizeimage($image){
    $img = ImageTool::resize(array(
                    'input' => $image,
                    'output' => 'img.jgp',
                    'width' => 100,
                    'height' => 100,
                    'keepRatio' => true,
                ));
                return ImageTool::saveImage($img,array(
                    'output' => 'img.jgp'
                ));
}

//envio archivo para ser procesado
$imgname = $image['tmp_name'];
                $img = $this->_risizeimage($imgname);
                var_dump($img);
                die();
```